# Can quantum mechanics be formulated without any reference to pictures?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

***NOTE:*** *in the following with the word "picture" I refer to [Schroedinger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture), [Heisenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture), [Interaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture) pictures, i.e. to the way the time-evolution is "distributed" between states and operators*.

We often switch, according to what is more suitable to the problem under consideration, between various pictures (Schroedinger, Heisenberg, Interaction, various combinations of the above). This is purely, to my understanding, to ease formal manipolations, and the physical content of the theory is always independent of the picture used to describe it.

Is it possible to formulate quantum mechanics in a way that completely avoids the use of various pictures? The time evolution of the matrix elements
$$ \langle \alpha | \hat{O} | \beta \rangle (t)$$
is enough (is it?) to characterize the system at any time. Is it possible, at least in principle, to carry out calculations using just this and without any reference to pictures?

Comment: Not even pure mathematics avoids *pictures*, since many important results are of the form: "If you are looking at the structures A over X, that is exactly the same as looking at the structures B over Y". (Examples are many abstract algebra results: To find the morphisms between two varieties is exactly the same as finding the morphisms between their rings of regular functions in the inverse direction). I guess what I'm saying is: What would it mean not to have a picture, if is it perfectly possible to have different mathematical theories be equivalent?

Comment: What textbook is feeding you this seemingly mis-information?

Comment: A "picture" is merely there to help humans develop an intuition. Ideally you don't have one picture of a physical process ready but half a dozen or more, and you need to know where the usefulness of these pictures ends. Mathematics alone is meaningless, there is no more an algorithm which would allow us to reason our way trough physics than there is an algorithm which allows mathematicians to do mathematics. The mathematicians even have a proof for that: look up formal logic and Goedel.

Comment: @ACuriousMind maybe I should have been more specific. I don't mean "picture" as a generic way to formulate a theory. I am referring to the switching between (e.g.) Schroedinger and Heisenberg pictures achieved by "unloading" the information about time evolution from states to operators. I could just as well completely avoid this problem by only studying the time-evolution of averages (or can I?), but I don't because in various situation this is not the best approach to make calculations easier.

Comment: @KyleKanos what are you referring to?

Comment: @glance: the fact that you think the formulations are somehow flawed because there are *other* QM formulations.

Comment: But the pictures *are* exactly the same. You can derive one from the other. Every result that holds in one holds in the others. There is no result (known to me, at least) about physically observable things that holds in one but not the others. And why would "studying time averages" (I'm not sure what precisely you mean) be qualitatively different from the other pictures, i.e. what makes it not just another picture?

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm sorry, when did I ever mentioned one formulation being flawed or even just "better" than another? Is the use of the word "careful" that gives that idea? If that is so I'll change it.

Comment: These "pictures" (*terrible* word) are just coordinate systems in a way. There's no lack of formality or rigour. Using different pictures is analogous to changing variables to do an integral.

Comment: @glance: the fact that you ask if a more rigorous way to do QM without these 'pictures' is what gives me the idea that you think the Heisenberg and Schrodinger are flawed.

Comment: @ACuriousMind sorry about "time-averages", I meant $\langle \hat{O} \rangle$ with $\hat{O}$ an observable. More generally, is it right to say that all the physical content of the theory is contained in the time evolution of the matrix elements $\langle \alpha | \hat{O} | \beta \rangle (t)$ with $\alpha, \beta$ the eigenstates in some representation? If so what I'm trying to understand is if the "breaking" of this time-evolution into one attributed to the state and another to the operator is merely to ease computations or if it can be formalized more rigorously

Comment: @KyleKanos the fact that a theory is completely fine doesn't mean it's not interesting to look at other ways to formulate it, does it? Anyway, I edited the question trying to be more clear in what I mean and what I'm asking for

Comment: A number of blind people have contributed to the development of quantum mechanics. Pictures are not needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you say, *pictures* in QM are merely different ways to compute the exact same thing - the expectation value of observables $\mathcal{O}$. Now, in *all pictures*, we can derive [Ehrenfest's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem)

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\langle \mathcal{O} \rangle = \frac{1}{\mathrm{i}\hbar}\langle [\mathcal{O},H]\rangle + \langle\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathcal{O}\rangle$$

which tells you how every expectation value evolves with time. It holds in all known pictures. In fact, it can be used to *derive* the Schrödinger equation. In this sense, it is an equivalent foundation of QM. As with all other ways of looking at QM, the fundamental insight here is that the Hamiltonian is the generators of time translations (just as it is in classical phase space mechanics, or the [Koopman-von Neumann formulation of mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopman%E2%80%93von_Neumann_classical_mechanics)).

There's no more rigor to be found. All pictures are equivalent (for example, the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem) shows Schrödinger and Heisenberg to be unitarily equivalent, essentially making the switch between them (as DanielSank comments) a basis change in Hilbert space) - you may start from the Schrödinger equation and say that time evolution operates on states, you may start from the Heisenberg time evolution and say that operators evolve, you may start from Ehrenfest's theorem. It's all the same.

Comment: 2 related questions:
1. Is it enough to talk about average values $\langle \mathcal{O} \rangle $? Shouldn't also non-diagonal matrix elements $\langle\alpha|\mathcal{O}|\beta\rangle$ be characterized?
2. Writing Ehrenfest's theorem this way, aren't we again making reference to a particular picture in which the operators are expressed? But if I had to express QM *only* using average values, I shouldn't talk about operators anymore, as these are necessarily expressed in some *picture*. This raises some problems: how should then something like $\langle [\mathcal{O},H]\rangle$ be interpreted?

Comment: to be more clear, I'm asking whether is possible to consider as the fundamental quantities characterizing the system *only* this averages, without any reference to the underlying operators (thus non interpreting them as "averages" anymore but just as numbers characterizing the system)

Comment: @glance: There's no "picture" in which operators or states are expressed. All that the "picture" you choose does is to tell you "where" time evolution goes. Essentially, you know that $\langle \alpha \rvert U^\dagger(t,t_0) \mathcal{O} U(t,t_0) \lvert \beta \rangle$ is the time evolution of a matrix element, and it is equivalent to consider the operator evolving or the states evolving or some mixture ala interaction picture. (Since Ehrenfest theorem is equivalent to the Schrödinger equation, it already contains the evolution of such matrix elements.)