# Picture-independence of quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, time-evolution

I've been thinking about the equivalence of the [Heisenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) and [Schrödinger pictures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture) of quantum mechanics in the following terms lately: a quantum system is a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ equipped with a set of basis vectors $|e_i>$, plus a vector $|\psi>$.

Observable quantities depend only upon the set of projections $<e_i|\psi>$ (I always get this backwards). Let's view the Hilbert space as a finite dimensional inner-product space to build intuition: then the projections depend only on the angles between $|\psi>$ and the $|e_i>$s.

Now by appeal to the spectral theorem the $|e_i>$s are the eigenvectors of some Hermitian matrix $\mathcal{O}$. If we wish to model a situation in which the outcomes of measurements might change over time, then, we have an uncountable set of options between two extremes:

1. The $|e_i>$s, and thus $\mathcal{O}$, can remain static, while $|\psi>$ rotates. This is the Schrodinger picture.
2. $|\psi>$ can remain static, while the $|e_i>$s rotate. This is the Heisenberg picture.
3. Any combination of the two leading to the same time-evolution of the projections.

Is this a reasonable point of view?

Comment: Related: [Can quantum mechanics be formulated without any reference to pictures?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141686/50583)